# Where is this excess horizontal space coming from?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am building a React.js website app for a university project which uses Reactstrap as well as my custom CSS. I have just noticed that I have horizontal scrolling but I cannot figure out where it is coming from.

You can see the extra space on the image, it seems to be something to do with the navbar but I just have no idea why and have played around with the CSS a lot. I must be completely missing something?

[image: Horizontal Space Example Screenshot]

Code for the Navbar.js component:

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar expand="md" className="custom-nav-bg fixed-top">
        <Navbar.Brand expand="lg" href="#home">
        <Link to="/home"><img className="custom-nav-logo"
            src="logohero.png"
            alt="StatHero Logo"
            width="105px"
            height="50px"
          /></Link>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav className="collapse navbar-collapse mr-auto justify-content-end">

          <Nav.Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#about">
          <Link to="/about">ABOUT</Link>
          </Nav.Link>

          <Nav.Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#stats">
          <Link to="/stats">STATS</Link>
          </Nav.Link>

          <Nav.Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#faqs">
          <Link to="/faq">FAQS</Link>
          </Nav.Link>

          <Nav.Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#contact">
          <Link to="/contact">CONTACT</Link>
          </Nav.Link>

          <Nav.Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#signup">
            <Button className="custom-nav-button">SIGN UP</Button>
          </Nav.Link>

          <Nav.Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#login">
          LOGIN
          </Nav.Link>

        </Nav>

    </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
export default NavBar;
```

Code for my custom.css:

```
  background-color: #132A42;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.custom-nav-logo {
  height: 100%;
}

a:focus, a:hover, a:active {
  color: white ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif ! important;
  font-weight: 650 ! important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.custom-nav-text:hover {
  color: white ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif ! important;
  font-weight: 700 ! important;
}

.custom-nav-text {
  color: white ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left:20px ! important;
  padding-right:20px ! important;
  padding-top:10px ! important;
  padding-bottom:10px ! important;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.custom-usp-1 {
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
}

.custom-usp-2 {
  background-color: white;
}

.custom-nav-button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #00DF8D;
  background-color: #00DF8D;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 15px;
  }

  .custom-jumbo-button {
    border-radius: 35px;
    border-color: #00DF8D;
    background-color: #00DF8D;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

.CTA {
  background-color: #C42B32;
}

.custom-jumbo {
  padding-bottom: 150px ! important;
  padding-top: 210px ! important;
  background-color: #132A42;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}

h1 {
  color: white ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px ! important;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h2 {
  color: white ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

p {
  color: white ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px ! important;
}

h3 {
  color: black ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h4 {
  color: #C42B32 ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.USPp {
  color: black ! important;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px ! important;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 60px ! important;
  padding-left: 60px ! important;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.customCard {
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: #C42B32 ! important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px ! important;
}

.cardContent {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125) ! important;
}

.JumboImg {
  background-color: #132A42;
  height: 500px;
}

.customFooter {
  background-color: #132A42;
  height: 200px;
}
 a {
   color: white;
 }
```

I can provide the code for the other components on the page if necessary.

Comment: can you extract the html and create a snippet so we can debug correctly plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

It was an issue with one of the other components.

I used dev tools to manually go through and delete elements to find out which one caused the horizontal scroll. I then edited the CSS for that component by adding

max-width: 100%;

This was a very helpful tutorial on how to do this:
https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/

Answer (score 1):

I think the body has some padding or margin...

add this class... I hope it will work:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see css for .custom-nav-bg and .fixed-top